# How to hide bus number from google direction service?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

i am developing an application in ionic that display bus routes on google map in TRANSIT travel modes. according to the requirement client want me to remove bus number marker from map.
image is attached below.

[image]

I am unable to hide these bus numbers.
Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no such option, you'll need to draw the route on you own(without using the DirectionsRenderer)

Comment: and how can i do that can you explain a bit?

Comment: @NeerajSharma did you find anything related to this?

Comment: hi @TWiStErRob i removed that element using javascript.